# Any way to use JavaScript to access/activate a Google SERP Instant Preview button?

Tags: javascript, dom, applescript

When looking at a Google search results page, such as http://www.google.com/search?q=test, is there any way to access (and thus activate) the 'Instant Preview' button for the first search result via JavaScript?  Such as in the document.?.? format?  The button has a `<button>` tag, but doesn't appear to lie within a  tag.  Each one looks like this: `<button class="vspib"></button>`

I'm asking because I'm writing an Applescript that is automating input into and selection from Google, and I want to turn on the instant preview programatically (i.e. with a 'do JavaScript ...' line).

*Also, just so there's no confusion, yes, I really want to be automating Google visually, so that one can watch the screen and see it automated.  I do not want to just find a way to automate queries (I know I could do that many other ways).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript will be.
document.getElementsByClassName('vspib')[0].click();